# Date Calculation in Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I am subtracting `DATE_IN` (`16-NOV-20 06:02 PM`) from `DATE_OUT` (`17-NOV-20 03:23 PM`).  I expect the answer to be `21.21` (hours.minutes), but it gives me `21.34` which is the correct hours but not the correct minutes.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function TIME_CALCULATIONFormula return NUMBER is
begin
    RETURN ROUND((((:DATE_OUT - :DATE_IN)*24)*60)/60,2);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is correct as 0.34 hours = 20.4 minutes.

If you want to return hours as the units and minutes as the decimal then you could use:

```sql
function TIME_CALCULATIONFormula return NUMBER
is
  diff INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := (:DATE_OUT - :DATE_IN) DAY TO SECOND;
begin
  RETURN EXTRACT( DAY FROM diff ) * 24
         + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM diff )
         + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ) / 100;
end;
```

or

```sql
function TIME_CALCULATIONFormula return NUMBER
is
  diff INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := CAST(:DATE_OUT AS TIMESTAMP)
                                 - CAST(:DATE_IN AS TIMESTAMP);
begin
  RETURN EXTRACT( DAY FROM diff ) * 24
         + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM diff )
         + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ) / 100;
end;
```

or

```sql
function TIME_CALCULATIONFormula return NUMBER
is
begin
  RETURN TRUNC( ( :date_out - :date_in ) * 24 ) +
         MOD( ( :date_out - :date_in ) * 24 * 60, 60 ) / 100;
end;
```

or, if you are not going to have time differences over 24 hours and want trailing zeroes on the numbers:

```sql
function TIME_CALCULATIONFormula return VARCHAR2
is
begin
  RETURN TO_CHAR( DATE '1900-01-01' + ( :date_out - :date_in ), 'HH24.MI' );
end;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=496c1dffc1062fbfc3256a0cad35c956)*

Comment: @MTO bundel of thanks for you reply  when i put this code in reports it show me error at function 'Encountered the symbol "day" when expecting'  I pasted the same code in rports

Comment: @aws I can only answer from the perspective of Oracle databases as I do not use Oracle reports and it works in an Oracle database (as you can see from the db<>fiddle); however, if Oracle Reports uses slightly different syntax then you will have to convert it from PL/SQL to the reports syntax. That said, there are 3 instances of the `DAY` keyword and I have no idea which of them is supposed to be raising your exception as you have not given an indication of which it is but I've edited in another version that will give the same output.

Comment: @MTO you are 1000% right sir its working on db<>fiddle i also check 2nd one also  but its not working in reports i know its syntax error which i am not able to overcome on that syntax any lot of thanks for your effort for your precious time which you gives to me  stay blessed and safe

Comment: @aws Updated with a 3rd option.

Comment: @MTO You are awesome i cant believe its worked but like it showed 21.2045 is it posible to show that 21.21 Did this 
         `ROUND(MOD( ( :date_out - :date_in ) * 24 * 60, 60 ) / 100,2);` but it shows me 21.2

Comment: @aws You are using a `NUMBER` data type and `21.20` and `21.2` have the same numeric value. If you want trailing zeroes then you cannot return a `NUMBER` and should be returning a formatted string instead.

Comment: @MTO Best Regards Your are awesome and kind man it can work for me same as I am very thankful to you, you gives me your precious time my best regards and wishes for you Stay blessed ever

Comment: Blessing is nice, @aws, but - you should accept the answer which helps the most (and/or upvote it, as well as others you find useful).

Answer (score 1):

The result you're getting is **not** "hours.minutes" - it's a decimal representation of the hours. 0.34 hour is 20 minutes and 24 seconds, which seems to be the result you're gunning for, up to the rounding error of the two decimal places you're forcing.

Comment: I know this is a decimal representation I don't know how to get as desired result please guide me